# ServiceStack Session is null in self-hosted server

Tags: c#, session, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

There is problem with `Session` in `Service`, `Session` is `null` on second call (solved, see bottom of the post).

I have self-hosted server and client that makes calls to server via `JsonServiceClient` and `ProtoBufServiceClient`.

On start of client application I call:

```
var baseUrl = ConfigGlobal.Host ;
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);

var authResponse = client.Post<AuthResponse>("/auth", new Auth
{
    UserName = "test1",
    Password = "password",
    RememberMe = true
});
```

It works - `OnAuthenticated` it's fired in my `CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession`.

```
authService.SaveSession(session);
```

didn't help.

Then in one class:

```
var client = new ProtoBufServiceClient(ConfigGlobal.Host);

client.Put(new ExcelInitialize {Filename = ""}); // OK
Model = client.Get(...); // Session is null
```

There is a problem in service class in `Get` method Session is `null`. If I implement

```
 public CustomUserSession CustomUserSession
 {
    get
    {
       return SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
    }
 }
```

I'll get: Only ASP.NET Requests accessible via Singletons are supported.

### My AppHost.cs

```
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
container.Register<ISessionFactory>(c => new SessionFactory(c.Resolve<ICacheClient>()));

Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new CustomUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[]
            {
                new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(),
                new BasicAuthProvider(),
            }));

        Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());
```

### Goal:

Send some variables from client and remember them on host until user logs off.

### Edit:

My Workflow looks like this:

SomeClass1:

- new auth service client->Post(new Auth(...));  // login ok
- nothing more

SomeClass2:

- new service client->Put(new E); // some init.
- service client->Get(new G);

Service G:

- on G request new service client TryResolve();
- client->Get(new W)

Service E

- on E request CustomUserSession accessible
- on W request CustomUserSession not accessible.

My Custom* classes looks like in Scott answer.

### Edit:

Here is the code of my problem ready to copy&paste:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Very basic console host
        var appHost = new AppHost();
        appHost.Init();
        appHost.Start("http://*:8082/");

        var url = "http://localhost:8082";

        var foo = new TestApp.SomeClass1(url);
        var bar = new TestApp.SomeClass2(url);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class AppService : Service
    {
        public CustomUserSession CustomUserSession
        {
            get
            {
                // Returns the typed session
                return SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
            }
        }
    }

    public class GService : AppService
    {
        public object Get(GRequest request)
        {
            var client = base.TryResolve<EService>();

            client.Get(new WRequest());

            return new { CustomUserSession.SuperHeroIdentity };
        }
    }

    public class EService : AppService
    {
        public void Get(WRequest wRequest)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CustomUserSession.SuperHeroIdentity);
        }

        public void Get(ERequest request)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CustomUserSession.SuperHeroIdentity);
        }

        public void Put(ERequest request)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CustomUserSession.SuperHeroIdentity);
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass1
    {
        public SomeClass1(string url)
        {
            var client = new JsonServiceClient(url);

            client.Post<AuthResponse>("/auth", new Auth
            {
                UserName = "clark.kent",
                Password = "kryptonite",
                RememberMe = true
            });
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass2
    {
        public SomeClass2(string url)
        {
            var client = new JsonServiceClient(url);

            client.Put(new ERequest());
            client.Get(new GRequest());
        }
    }

public class GRequest : IReturnVoid
{
}

public class ERequest : IReturnVoid
{
}

public class WRequest : IReturnVoid
{
}
```

### Solution (for this problem):

1. Save session cookies in client application and restore them before every call to Webservice.
2. Use Service::Resolve() instead of Service::TryResolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted looks okay to me. So it's likely something trivial with your setup.

I have created a simple, self hosted app which also uses a `CustomUserSession` and a `CustomCredentialsAuthProvider`, hopefully using this as a guide will highlight what is going wrong. Let me know how you get on.

```cs
using ServiceStack.CacheAccess;
using ServiceStack.CacheAccess.Providers;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth;
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;

namespace Testv3
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Very basic console host
            var appHost = new AppHost();
            appHost.Init();
            appHost.Start("http://*:8082/");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("Test Service", typeof(TestApp).Assembly) {}

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            // Cache and session IoC
            container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
            container.Register<ISessionFactory>(c => new SessionFactory(c.Resolve<ICacheClient>()));

            // Register the Auth Feature with the CustomCredentialsAuthProvider.
            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
                () => new CustomUserSession(), 
                new IAuthProvider[]
                {
                    new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(),
                    new BasicAuthProvider(),
                })
            );
        }
    }

    public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
    {
        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            // Replace with a database lookup
            return (userName == "clark.kent" && password == "kryptonite");
        }

        public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
        {
            var customSession = session as CustomUserSession;
            if(customSession != null)
            {
                // Replace these static values with a database lookup
                customSession.FirstName = "Clark";
                customSession.LastName = "Kent";
                customSession.SuperHeroIdentity = "Superman";
            }
            authService.SaveSession(customSession, SessionExpiry);
        }
    }

    public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession 
    {
        // Our added session property
        public string SuperHeroIdentity { get; set; }
    }

    public static class TestApp
    {
        [Route("/SuperHeroTime", "GET")]
        public class SuperHeroTimeRequest {}

        public class TestController : Service
        {
            public CustomUserSession CustomUserSession
            {
                get 
                { 
                    // Returns the typed session
                    return SessionAs<CustomUserSession>(); 
                }
            }

            [Authenticate]
            public object Get(SuperHeroTimeRequest request)
            {
                // Return the result object
                return new { CustomUserSession.FirstName, CustomUserSession.LastName, Time = DateTime.Now.ToString(), CustomUserSession.SuperHeroIdentity };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you put this `index.html` in your `bin` folder and navigate to `http://localhost:8082/index.html` you can call the service, to test it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function login()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/auth/credentials",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        UserName: "clark.kent",
                        Password: "kryptonite",
                        RememberMe: true
                    })
                }).done(function(result){
                    getSuperHeroTime();
                });
            }
            function getSuperHeroTime()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/SuperHeroTime",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                }).done(function(result){
                    $("#result").html(result.FirstName + " " +
                                    result.LastName + " is " +
                                    result.SuperHeroIdentity + " (" +
                                    result.Time + ")");
                });
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Super Hero Time</h1>
    <button onclick="login()">Go</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Update:

1. Having looked at your usage code provided in your edit. You are calling the Auth method in `SomeClass1` and then that `JsonServiceClient` isn't reused. So your session won't follow. You have to reuse the client, because the client stores the cookies that track your session.

   In `SomeClass2` you are effectively calling the service without authenticating, so the session is `null`. You need to reuse the same `JsonServiceClient` for your requests.

   You could run your authentication method and then pass the session cookies to any subsequent `JsonServiceClient`, to save re-authenticating with each client. It's easy to do:

   ```
   var authClient = new JsonServiceClient(url);
   authclient.Post<AuthResponse>("/auth", new Auth {
       UserName = "clark.kent",
       Password = "kryptonite",
       RememberMe = true
   });

   // Get the session cookies
   var cookies = authClient.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(url));

   // In your other `JsonServiceClient`s set the cookies before making requests
   var anotherClient = new JsonServiceClient(url);
   anotherClient.CookiesCollection.add(cookies);

   anotherClient.Post( ...
   ```
2. You are also trying to resolve another service within your service using:

   ```
   base.TryResolve<EService>();
   ```

   You need to use this instead, or you will see the `Only ASP.NET Requests accessible via Singletons are supported` exception:

   ```
   base.ResolveService<EService>();
   ```

Comment: @Tomasito I have changed the code to be v3 code. Can you see if that version works for you, I have it running without an issue, Can you post your `CustomUserSession` and `CustomCredentialsAuthProvider`, if you're still stuck. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using a new client because calls are asynchronous `var foo = new AsynchronousCommand (() => {var new client})`, now I would have to use the client as singleton or send Auth() on every request? The second point is a very serious limitation.

Comment: @Tomasito I have updated the answer. I believe it now addresses all the issues for you to get working code. You should first make the call the authentication method, then save the cookies collection and pass that onto any other clients that will make requests, that will ensure they are authenticated. And ensure you change your `TryResolve` to `ResolveService` and the exception will go away.

Comment: @Tomasito Just an FYI, the `JsonServiceClient` also supports `Async` methods such as `GetAsync`, `PostAsync` etc, that may be easier.

Comment: Do you mean `client.CookieContainer.Add(_cookies);`? I know about Async methods but I already have async ViewModel. Now the example works :) tomorrow I'll try it in full aplication.

Comment: @Tomasito You can pass the cookies any way you want, or store them in another accessible variable. i.e. `_cookies = authClient.CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(url));` if thats how you want to do it. Or have your authentication mechanism return the `CookieContainer`. The point I am making is you will always have to do your authentication, then get the cookies, then you can kick off as many other requests asynchronously as you need, given that you pass the cookies back in.